# Request an access token from Microsoft OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, httprequest, single-sign-on

I am trying to use SSO from Microsoft account which is explained in [Request Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?tabs=http#2-request-authorization).

I have done registering app and request authorization so I code from Microsoft but I am not able to get request an access token which Microsoft given example like:

```
// Line breaks for legibility only
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
&scope=user.read%20mail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=HF8Q~Krjqh4r...    // NOTE: Only required for web apps
```

I have written this code using RestSharp:

```
string URI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token";

string myParameters = "client_id="+clientID+"&scope=User.Read%20Mail.Read&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8756%2FStep1Resp.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret="+clientSec;

var client = new RestClient(URI);

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", myParameters,  ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string resp=response.Content;
```

I am getting error

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use HttpClient instead of Restsharp.
First try use postman make the request successfully like below.
[image]

On the right side of postman open code-snippet,it automatically generate c#codes.
[image]
Copy all the codes to a console application, it will work. (Only for HttpClient way, the RestSharp still has problem).
[image]